# change server timezone into specific timezone using php

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, timezone

In phpmyadmin under date_time row the time value updated like this

```
2015-02-22 00:40:54
```

Well, This code is working fine for a single value

```
$timezone = new DateTimeZone('America/Vancouver');

$date = new DateTime(date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time()));
$date->setTimeZone($timezone);
$msg_time = $date->format('h:i A M d'); // current time
```

But what if I get a row from db like this

```
$msg_time = date('h:i A M d',strtotime($row["date_time"]));
```

again it is showing the server time for "date" so how to fix this, not need to show the client's time using js but just want to show the time in a specific timezone instead of server timezone.

The full code is here in plain txt: http://dnetbd.com/shout_php.txt

Answer (score 0):

You can always get the GMT offset between the timezones and do some math...